# Jest toBeCloseTo for objects

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to check two matrices that are approximately equal.

In jest, we have `toEqual` to check two equality of two objects, but cannot compare its floating number properties that are approximately equal; we also have `toBeCloseTo`, but it can only compare two floating numbers rather than apply the approximate equality strategy to all floating number property in an object.

I don't want to compare every floating number property by hand, because this may lose the verbose result that shows the diff of two objects.
(The matrix object also contains other non-floating number fields, e.g. strings)

Is there a better way to compare two matrices approximately? How can I do that?

Comment: With custom matcher, I guess. Write your own that iterates over arrays and uses toBeCloseTo on each element. Check the internals of toEqual regarding result output https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/src/matchers.ts . Probably could be pasted used as a base, but it uses broader equality checks that aren't limited to numeric arrays so iterableEquality helper needs to be modified too https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/src/utils.ts#L152 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature offered in Jest.

A workaround I eventually end up with is just to compare all elements of a matrix by using `toBeCloseTo`. However, a practice I've made is that use a flag for the test and set automatically if we really need to check the floating point closely, then the test will use `toBeCloseTo` instead of `toEqual`. For instance:

```
// closeCheck is a flag indicating if we want to check floating points closely.
if (closeCheck) { // approx equal, default precision: 2
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.elems.length; i++) {
    expect(matrix.elems[i]).toBeCloseTo(want.elems[i])
  }
// otherwise we just compare using toEqual.
} else expect(matrix).toEqual(want)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with the [closeTo](https://jestjs.io/docs/29.4/expect#expectclosetonumber-numdigits) method of the `AsymmetricMatchers` in `expect` like so:

```
function createGreyScaleRgb(num) {
  return { red: num / 255, green: num / 255, blue: num / 255 };
}

const expected = {
  red: expect.closeTo(0.75),
  green: expect.closeTo(0.75),
  blue: expect.closeTo(0.75),
};

expect(createGreyScaleRGB(192)).toEqual(expected);
```